# cURL Mail Attachment (Imagines, .exe file, .rar/.zip files)

Tags: file, email, curl, exe, attachment

I was wondering if I can send different type of files to an email as an attachments. I only know how to send a text file using cUrl. Could someone give me some examples of how can I accomplish my goal ?

This is what I have so far :

```
curl --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --mail-from "mail.gaming@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "mail2@gmail.com" --ssl --user "mail@gmail.com:password" --upload-file "C:\Folder\File.txt"
```

**Thank you for all the effort !**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multipart/mixed` content to transmit your text body and each of your binary attachments.

Here is a template of file you could use to display a text file and attach 2 binary files :

```
From: Some Name <sender@gmail.com>
To: Some Name <receiver@gmail.com>
Subject: example of mail
Reply-To: Some Name <sender@gmail.com>
Cc: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY"

--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY"

--MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline

This is an email example. This is text/plain content inside the mail.
--MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY--
--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.rar"
<HERE BASE64 ENCODED RAR FILE>


--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"
<HERE BASE64 ENCODED ZIP FILE>


--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY--
```

Note that the binary files are encoded in base64 and are transmitted as `attachment`.
Here is an example of building this file and send the email with a `bash` script :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rtmp_url="smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587"
rtmp_from="sender@gmail.com"
rtmp_to="receiver@gmail.com"
rtmp_credentials="sender@gmail.com:secretpassword"

file_upload="data.txt"

echo "From: Some Name <$rtmp_from>
To: Some Name <$rtmp_to>
Subject: example of mail
Reply-To: Some Name <$rtmp_from>
Cc: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY\"

--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY\"

--MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline

This is an email example. This is text/plain content inside the mail.
--MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY--
--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.rar\"" > "$file_upload"

# convert file.rar to base64 and append to the upload file
cat file.rar | base64 >> "$file_upload"

echo "--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.zip\"" >> "$file_upload"

# convert file.zip to base64 and append to the upload file
cat file.zip | base64 >> "$file_upload"

# end of uploaded file
echo "--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY--" >> "$file_upload"

# send email
echo "sending ...."
curl -s "$rtmp_url" \
     --mail-from "$rtmp_from" \
     --mail-rcpt "$rtmp_to" \
     --ssl -u "$rtmp_credentials" \
     -T "$file_upload" -k --anyauth
res=$?
if test "$res" != "0"; then
   echo "sending failed with: $res"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

The received email will have the `inline` `text/plain` document and both of `attachment` document of type `application/octet-stream` :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. However, to send inline text, I have to convert the text into base64. Otherwise I get illegible chars.

`$(echo "This is an email example. This is text/plain content inside the mail." | base64)`

Comment: or you remove the line that states ``Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
`` right above the content.